# I have 10 divs that load at the same time and need to add a seperate timer to each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a list of 10 divs that load at the same time. I need to apply a seperate timer to each one that will display a time frame based on ordered time minus current time. I can only get the timer to display in the first loaded div and none of the rest. Any ideas what I am doing wrong in my code?

here is the jQuery to load the list:

```
$('#orderList').append("<li id='listOrd'><div id='numDiv"+val.id+"' class='orderListBtn'><div class='orderListBtnTxt'><img id='myImage' onload='counter()' class='noImage' src='Images/NewOrderIcon.png'>"+" " +val.id+"<br> " +val.location+"<br> " +val.playername+"<br> " +val.items[0].itemticketname+" <br>" +val.totalprice+"<br> " +val.transtime+"<br> "+"<span id='r'></span></div></div></li>");
```

and below is the timer

```
<script  type="text/javascript">chNum = "<?php include('aphpfile.php')?>";

  function counter() {setInterval(function(){       
    var t = parseInt(chNum);

    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff =  now.getTime() - t;

    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    //var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        hours %= 24;
        minutes %= 60;
        seconds %= 60;

    r=document.getElementById('r');
    r.textContent = hours + ':' + minutes +':'+ seconds;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: please fiddle this code...

Comment: I have never used fiddle and do not know how to place the code in a fiddle.

Comment: its never too late to learn :) http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html

Comment: Fiddle just changed their UI, I don't like it. Anyway, what is `val` in your script?

Comment: $.each(data.orders, function(key, val)  The onload event is in the top line of code, onload='counter()'.

Comment: @Chizzle -- if you don't like JSFiddle why not recommend StackOverflow's [StackSnippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) (runnable Javascript, HTML and CSS snippets).  Both tools are IDEAL for creating a _minimal, complete, and verifiable example_.  JSFiddle has been valuable in this way to many people, despite your low-opinion of it.